# Visual Studio 2008 (Pro): create MSI for powershell script?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, wix, windows-installer

I have a PS script which needs a shortcut to run it, which is no problem; but is there any way of using the *File System Editor* from VS2008 to wrap all this into an MSI? I can do it with an existing VS project but have no idea how to target an external script.
After more Googling it appears that I can install WIX and do it manually from there, but there must be an easier way surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sapien powershell studio for this : https://www.sapien.com/blog/2013/06/05/introducing-the-msi-wizard/

another method that you can give try is (tested with visual studio 2015):

- install "powershell tools for visual studio" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2015) and create a powershell project with your source files
- then install "installer projects" ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) to create installer for powershell and add a setup project to the existing powershell project

Comment: Many thanks, sir. I will see if this works with VS2008.